# Explanation to understand a VBA code for percentage change

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

I am learning to create formulas in VBA from the internet, and I came across this article by Jon from excel campus where he was teaching to create formulas for the percentage change.

I, however, was not able to understand a part of the code, where he used the double inverted commas and the ampersand sign while creating the formula.

**sFormula = "=IFERROR((" & sNew & " - " & sOld & ")/" & sOld & ",0)"**

Can someone please tell me why the ampersand sign is used in between sNew and sOld, and also why not using the inverted commas and the ampersand sign leads to the failure of the code?

The full coding is as follows-

```
Sub Percent_Change_Formula()
'Description: Creates a percentage change formula
'Source: https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/percentage-change-formulas-macro/

Dim rOld As Range
Dim rNew As Range
Dim sOld As String
Dim sNew As String
Dim sFormula As String


'End the macro on any input errors
'or if the user hits Cancel in the InputBox
On Error GoTo ErrExit

'Prompt the user to select the cells
Set rNew = Application.InputBox( _
        "Select the cell that contains the NEW number", _
        "Select New Cell", Type:=8)
Set rOld = Application.InputBox( _
        "Select the cell that contains the OLD number", _
        "Select Old Cell", Type:=8)

'Get the cell addresses for the formula - relative references
sNew = rNew.Address(False, False)
sOld = rOld.Address(False, False)
    
'Create the formula
sFormula = "=IFERROR((" & sNew & " - " & sOld & ")/" & sOld & ",0)"

'Create the formula in the activecell
ActiveCell.Formula = sFormula

ErrExit:
    
End Sub
```

Comment: It's important to use the correct terminology so you can look stuff up. They are not inverted commas. They're double quotes.

Comment: @DanielB - in some countries, they are referred to as inverted commas. This is true in the UK at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA, the [ampersand operator (&)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ampersand-operator) is:

> Used to force string concatenation of two expressions.

The formula is created/built dynamically that's why the ampersand is used to append/concatenate the different parts.

> also why not using the inverted commas and the ampersand sign leads to the failure of the code?

If you don't use the ampersand and write for example:

```
sFormula = "=IFERROR(("  sNew " - "  sOld  ")/"  sOld & ",0)"
```

You get an error as the compiler expects an end of statement due to the fact there are spaces between the different strings and string variables (sNew and sOld). The compiler won't know what to do with all of them being on a same line.

Comment: And "concatenate" is a fancy word for "append". You might want to add that to your answer. Many non-native English speakers have never heard of concatenate before.

Comment: @Tonny Done as requested.